# Miracast with Miraclecast with Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.04, streaming

I am trying configure and use Miracast on my XPS 15 with Ubuntu 17.04. I came across this project https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast. I have followed the building steps and installed it. Now the documentation is not very clear (at least to me) on what to do next. It says the following:

```
$ sudo kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep wpa_supplican[t] | awk '{print $2}')
# now you can use `res/kill-wpa.sh`

>Remember to save your config to use with `res/normal-wifi.sh`
>it will be easily located with `ps -ef | grep wpa_supplicant` on `-c` option.
```

When I ran this in the terminal my wifi turned off. Then it says:

```
$ sudo miracle-wifid &
```

Here I get the error

> command not found

Answer (score 1):

Try running the command from the `src` folder.

Once you build `miraclecast` using `make`, the executables will be generated in the corresponding directories, then copied to system directories when you run `make install`

so try this:

```
cd /<miraclecast_directory>/src/wifi/
sudo ./miracle-wifid --log-level 7 &
```

`--log-level 7` will enable trace level logs